# What is the difference between two AT-command interfaces

Tags: linux, cellular-radio, radio-firmware

Qualcomm SDM660(modem- MSM4114), Mi A2, Android One 9(stock), 2 sim

I founded two devices(not links), that can recieve at commands and answer them. Its /dev/smd8 and smd11. Smd7 is owned by root:root, smd11 - radio:radio.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: Modem interfaces are proprietary. Those aren't officially documented. Instead closed source HALs in userspace communicate with them. So their exact purpose and capabilities are hardly well-known. You can experiment with them to explore things. Use `inotify`, `audit` etc. to know when and which kernel interface is accessed by which userspace process. Vendor's `init` and `ueventd` `.rc` files are also useful for some interfaces sometimes.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223967